# Javascript | Simple Form Validation Wont Work

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have been working on this really simple login, where all i want to do is say, if the password is "apple" and password is "123" then link me to another page when i click submit button.

I gave up on the submit button linking portion but i still don't understand why my code won't register, everything looks right to me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <form name="loginForm">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" value=""/>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" value=""/>
        <input type="button" name="submit" value="Login" onclick="validate()" />
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validate() {

            var user = document.loginForm.username.value;
            return user;
            var pass = document.loginForm.password.value;
            return pass;

            if ( (user=="apple") && (pass=="123") ) {
                document.write("It worked");
            } else {
                document.write("Wrong Password");
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There are 2 return statements in your code. Code after `return user` will never be executed.

Comment: just remove the 2 return statements and you are good..

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

- return keyword will exit the function, so the code after return won't be reached. To remove the two '*return*' statement is the first step.
- document.write will clear the page after document is loaded. You probably need alert function
- try using document.getElementById/getElementByName (which is better) instead of document.loginForm...
- It is also better to put `onsubmit` in the form tag (fired after type=submit button is clicked) instead of *onclick* event for button.
- It is better to put Javascript inside the HTML *head* tag.

Below is a much better/working version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validate() {
            var user = document.getElementById("username").value;
            var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
            if ( (user=="apple") && (pass=="123") ) {
                alert("It worked");
                return true;
            } else {
                alert("Wrong password");
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" onsubmit='javascript:return validate()'>
        <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username" value=""/>
        <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" value=""/>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```